# Is there a way to update a dictionary's keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I have a program in Python where I find the average of a list within a dictionary. The dictionary has 5 keys and 5 lists as values. Each key is mapped to its value of lists. After I successfully find the average of each list, I try to map each average to each key. However, I only get the last average as each key's average...

I have a nested for loop, one for the keys and then one for the values of the keys. I have this in the key for loop:

`averagedict[key] = averageVal`

Outside of both loops, I have the return statement `return averagedict`

It gives me each key and the last average like this: `{'key1': averageVal, 'key2' : averageVal, ...}` It seems like for each key, it goes through all averages of the values, but only applies the last average value for each key. I am not sure how to leave the first key once that average is computed to go to the next key and compute that average?

Comment: `new_dict = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k, v in old_dict.items()}` try this

Comment: it did work!! thank you so much! i was going crazy over this haha

Comment: @llama: in the future, consider posting your code rather than trying to describe it verbally; it's really hard to read that kind of description and it can often hide bugs which are in the actual code.

Comment: I'm sorry, when you have a question like this, you **must** provide a [mcve].